# Access From an API in container A to a SQL server in docker container B

Tags: sql-server, docker, api, networking

I try to have my project containerized but encounter an issue I cant get my head around.

What I do:

1. Create a network =>  docker network create Network-Dev
2. Create a SQL server on the network (port 1440) => docker run --hostname SQL-server --network Network-Dev -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=passwordsAreOverrated@dev2023" -e "MSSQL_PID=Express" -p 1440:1433 -d --name dev-SQL -v //c/mount/sql:/var/opt/mssql/data mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
3. Create API on network => docker run --rm --name Dev-API --network Network-Dev -p 5000:80 api-dev

What happens:
The Network is created, the SQL server is running (and accessible on the host machine by SSMS on 127.0.0.1,1440)

BUT => When the API tries to connect to the SQLserver it gets an error => using connectionstring "Server=SQL-server,1440; User Id=sa; Password=passwordsAreOverrated@dev2023; Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=false;"

Error from .Net application:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

When inspecting the network via docker (docker network inspect Network-Dev) I see the network as bridge with the two containers.

I would like to understand what I am missing here and if it is possible even a sollution to the problem ;)

Thanx for reading all of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Docker network, you use the unmapped port numbers, so you should use port 1443. Since that's the default, you can leave it out in your connection string:

```
Server=SQL-server; User Id=sa; Password=passwordsAreOverrated@dev2023; Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=true;Integrated Security=false;
```

You only need to map the port to a host port if you need to access it from the host. If you only need to access the SQL server from the API container, you don't need to map the SQL server port.

Comment: Thank you! You are kidding me.. after 4 hours of digging and plowing..
Can you explain me why it wont work with the port number?

(And thanx! it works!!)

Comment: For me, it helps to think of the docker network as having 3 different machines on it: the host, the database and the API. The containers can talk to each other directly on the docker network using the `--hostname`. Port mappings are used when you want to access a container from the host. In your case, you can access the database using the host's IP address and port 1440. But the API container talks over the docker network, so it should use port 1443. And since 1443 is the default SQL server port, you don't need to specify it in the connection string.

Comment: (The `docker run --name` of the container, not the `--hostname`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Then I'm confused, since Gijsbert has `--hostname SQL-server --name dev-SQL` on his `docker run` command and it seems to work with `Server=SQL-server` in the connection string?

Comment: @DavidMaze => It is even more confusing to me;
- I have a host with SQL-server(Developer edition) on it
- have a docker container with SQL-server on it

Since the console tool I am working on is in another container on Docker it can access the SQL-server via its --hostname "SQL-server"  BUT I am not finding a way to connect to this containerized SQL server via the host SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)
This is very inconvenient since debugging requires often a look upon the data.. any thoughts on it?

Comment: @DavidMaze  What I now have done is: add the ports back and it works.. weirdly.
now the only thing is that in order to connect to the docker-sql server I need to stop the SQL server on my local machine.. something to work on ;)

Comment: Now I have it working! => The trick is to:
- use two ports => -p 1433:1433 -p 1430:1433 
1433 is used internally by the docker containers , 1430 can also be used from outside

Order:
- The host SQL server must be started first (otherwise will fail because another SQL server(container) is on port 1433
- start container SQL server

- start software in containers

Comment: i thought you have to create a bridge network between Api and Sqlserver within the docker in order to communicate them.